# VBA Collect information from found column through loop in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize ahead of time, I've never really used VBA and probably never will afterwards.

A friend has asked me to create an edit document button based on an ID provided. I have a loop that sifts through the database sheet in order to match the IDs.

My goal is that once the ID is found, collect all data from that found row. I was thinking if its possible to use
Range(i + "1").Value ... to Range(i + "10").Value to collect the data.
Obvious problem seems to be that the columns are preset of a letter, not a number.

I was wondering if I could have some help venturing into VBA/Excel and what I could do inside the If statement in order to collect the data/values I wish to grab from the found row.

Here's what I have right now.

```
Sub Load_Edit()
Sheets("SearchEstimation").Select

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
intValueToFind = Range("B5").Value

Sheets("EstimationDB").Select
For i = 1 To 500    ' VBA column.length?
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = intValueToFind Then
        Sheets("EstimationDB").Select
        Range(i + "1").Value

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")

End Sub
```

Comment: try `cells(i, 1).Value ... to cells(i, 10).Value` but there are vastly more efficient methods of finding a number in a column of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess a little as you didn't specify "to collect the data/values", so I assumed a simple .copy. Also I assumed that in the DB are no empty cells in between.
What about this:

```
Sub Load_Edit()
Dim wssearch as worksheet, wsDB as worksheet
Set wssearch = Sheets("SearchEstimation")
Set wsDB = Sheets("EstimationDB")

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
intValueToFind = wssearch.Range("B5").Value

Do
    i = i+1
    If wsDB.Cells(i, 1).Value = intValueToFind Then
        wsDB.Rows(i).copy 'Copy the whole row
        Exit Sub
    End If
'Break the loop if the cell is empty
Loop until wsDB.Cells(i,1).Value = ""

' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
MsgBox ("Value not found in the database!")

End Sub
```

You could replace my Do...Loop with a Foreach.